# How to use the sum function when already using an indirect function in googlesheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

`=SUM((INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6) & "'!$AH$28"),(INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6) & "'!$AI$28"))`

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Find a sheet name that has "Week" and "[number]" in the sheet name. (the number is the current row -6)
2. On that sheet found, I then want to sum up a range between cells AH28 and AV28. (I thought maybe it could work by manually adding the indirect part and the new cell number)

I'm pretty certain step 1 works, as I use a similar code/function in another sheet.
Am I not using the SUM part of the function right?

Do you know why this isn't working please?

Thank you!

`=SUM((INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6) & "'!$AH$28"),(INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6) & "'!$AI$28"))`

I get a #REF error saying that parameter "Week 2" is not a valid cell/range reference.

Alternatively, I could use =IFERROR(SUM('Week 1'!$AH$28:$AV$28),""), but I'm trying to avoid changing the week number of the sheet name manually many times.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your data is structured. But if you are currently referring correctly to each cell, use SUM as you would with tho cell references, with ":"

=SUM(INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6 & "'!$AH$28"):INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6 & "'!$AI$28"))

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now!
For anyone else needing something like this, here's what I changed:

=IFERROR(SUM((INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6 & "'!$AH$28") : INDIRECT("'Week " & ROW()-6 & "'!$AV$28"))), "~")

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! I had one extra parenthesis that just erased. Consider marking the question as answered 